# How to read tweet/text with ellipsis in R

Tags: r

I am trying to read tweets from a bunch of different text files and then count the number of characters in each tweet.

The code I am using the read the individual text files is the following:

```
nbc <- readLines(".../nbchealthnews.txt", 
                    encoding = "utf-10") %>%
map(., str_split_fixed, "\\|", 3) %>%
map_df(., as_tibble)
```

I then want to run

```
nbc_tweetLength <- nchar(nbc$V3)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
> nbc_tweetLength <- nchar(nbc$V3)
Error in nchar(nbc$V3) : invalid multibyte string, element 271
```

Element 271 is

```
> nbc$V3[271]
[1] "RT @JuliaSommerfeld: Tales of chucking big jobs are the new lady porn RT @ELLEmagazine: What's REALLY causing women to burn out before 30: \u0085"
```

while the corresponding actual tweet in the text file is

```
RT @JuliaSommerfeld: Tales of chucking big jobs are the new lady porn RT @ELLEmagazine: What's REALLY causing women to burn out before 30: …
```

How I can read the tweet as it is. That is, read the ellipsis that appears after the colon as it is, so that the text of the tweet remains unchanged?

If that is not possible, how can I circumvent the issue of counting the total number of characters in each tweet while accounting for special characters such as `\x85` and `\u0092` (the latter appears in another tweet when it is read into R; in the original text, this is a curly apostrophe (`’`).

Comment: Try `stringi::stri_read_lines` instead of `readLines` and `stringi::stri_length` and read up in `stringi`'s docs on how to convert to UTF-8

Comment: @hrbrmstr : Thanks for your help! Using `stringi::stri_read_lines` with `"encoding = auto"` seems to do the trick!